# Is it possible to have a default value in the LocalStorage for a Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I want to have a default value for my cordova application in the LocalStorage with key `{isFirstRun: true}`. When I launch the app, it would check the existence of the key, do some action and remove it.

Is it possible to add on build stage?

Comment: I don't know about cordava, but you will have a start function that initiates everything. Have an IIFE and set LS there with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, more or less ?

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
var settings = storage.getItem('settings');
if(!settings){
    storage.setItem('settings', '{"isFirstRun":true}');
    settings = {isFirstRun:true};
}
```